# Group each set of consecutive seats within a row_id in Snowflake

Tags: group-by, window-functions, snowflake

I want to group row_id and seat_number as follows so I can group by row_id and group_id (desired column) to pick the minimum seat number as start_seat and the maximum seat number as end_seat:

```
row_id seat_number group_id
a      1           0
a      2           0
a      3           0
a      6           1
a      7           1
a      8           1
b      6           2
b      7           2
b      8           2
b      11          3
b      12          3
```

I have tried countless approaches using window functions, including row_number(), lead(), etc. but I do not end up with the desired result. Using the subtraction approach doesn't capture the variation across row_id's. I need something that captures variation within and across row_id's.

Currently, the following lengthy process has worked

```
grouped_seats as (
    select 
        row_id,
        seat_number,
        rank() over (partition by row_id order by seat_number) as group_index
    from seats
),

lead_index as (
    select
        *,
        lead(group_index, 1, 0) over (partition by row_id order by group_index) as next_row
    from grouped_seats
),

max_seat as (
    select
        row_id,
        seat_number as end_seat
    from lead_index
    where next_row = 0
),

min_seat as (
    select
        row_id,
        seat_number as start_seat
    from lead_index
    where group_index = 1
),

row_seat as (
    select
        lead_index.row_id,
        min_seat.start_seat,
        max_seat.end_seat
    from lead_index
    left join min_seat
        on lead_index.row_id = min_seat.row_id
    left join max_seat
        on lead_index.row_id = min_seat.row_id
)

select *
from row_seat
```